# Is it possible to filter duplicate questions from search results?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I'm trying to identify duplicate questions pertaining to Javascript books and tutorials (so that I can identify them as such), but I keep seeing duplicates in my search results. Is there an option to filter out duplicate questions from search results on the Stack Exchange Network?

For example, this search results page on Stack Overflow contains a few duplicates, and I want to filter the duplicates (if possible): https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+books

Comment: Filtering out duplicate questions from would make it easier to identify duplicate questions that haven't yet been merged. This shouldn't necessarily be done by default, but it would be a useful option for power users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure requests like these are low on the radar, usually I refer these types of questions to be answered using http://data.stackexchange.com

I did a little research https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=duplicates

There were a some dodgy techniques:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76446/number-of-questions-closed-as-duplicates

And some good techniques:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73118/find-original-questions-referenced-posts-of-duplicates

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73335/questions-that-are-closed-excluding-duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do it right now, but it would be very useful because when reading an answer it's normal to give a look to the whole topic and therefore listing it multiple times in the search results is pointless.

I don't know what is the best way to add this to one of the feature requests, but I really feel the site needs this feature. Especially because when it is done server-side, it should be quite easy to implement (I suppose).

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible to filter duplicates from searches. See this search query for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%3A0